# Calling the contents of a cell inside a SUMIF function

Tags: function, google-sheets, sumifs, google-sheets-formula

I have a budgeting spreadsheet where I am trying to get the sum of cells in col A if the string in Col B is a certain keyword. For example, one of my formulas is `=SUMIF(D13:D36,"Restaurant",C13:C36)`, so if any of cells in Col D are `Restaurant`, it takes the amount in Col C and adds them up. I have about 10 of the same formula, each with a unique string/keyword. This function works fine.

My problem is when I add a lot of entries and my columns get longer than the code specifies, I need to go into each formula separately and update the cells (eg, change `C13:C36` to `C13:C45`, but 10 times).

If I enter "C13" into a cell, for this example `T1`, is it possible to call the contents in cell `T1` within the `SUMIF` function? So the function would look something like `=SUMIF(D13:D36,"Restaurant",CELL(T1):C36)`. I know the `CELL` function doesn't work here but is there something that could?

What I am trying to do is write the start and ending cells somewhere in my sheet then call them inside the `SUMIF` function, so if I need to change them later I only need to update 4 cells rather than 10+.

Answer (score 2):

First as stated in the comments, there is no cost to using full columns:

```
=SUMIF(D:D,"Restaurant",C:C)
```

Which now it does not matter how large it gets.

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel)

But if one wants to limit it using other cells, I would use INDEX, instead of INDIRECT as INDIRECT is volatile(This only works in Excel):

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(D:D,T1):INDEX(D:D,T2),"Restaurant",INDEX(C:C,T1):INDEX(C:C,T2))
```

Where Cell T1 holds the start row and T2 holds the end row.

Comment: Ah so this only works in Excel? In sheets I am getting a `Argument must be a range.` error; however, it works when I remove `T1` and `T2` and make the range the whole column

Comment: The whole columnn answer will work on both. The second only works onExcel, which you tagged. @vytfla

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake, I am using sheets. As you mentioned, I am indeed trying to limit cells rather than using the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

you could use simple `QUERY` like:

```
=QUERY({C13:D}, "select Col2, sum(Col1) 
                 where Col2 matches 'Restaurant' 
                 group by Col2 
                 label sum(Col1)''", 0)
```

or for the whole group:

```
=QUERY({C13:D}, "select Col2, sum(Col1) 
                 where Col2 is not null 
                 group by Col2 
                 label sum(Col1)''", 0)
```